# Hadoop Spark docker swarm where pyspark gives BlockMissingException but file is fine

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, docker-swarm

Based on https://github.com/gotthardsen/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench/tree/master/swarm I have a docker swarm setup with hadoop, spark, hue and a jupyter notebook setup.

Using Hue I uploaded a file to hdfs, and I have not problem downloading or viewing the file from hue or in hdfs on the namenode. There is no missing blocks and file check says everything is fine.

But when I try to access it using pyspark in jupyter I get a:

> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException: Could not obtain block:
>   BP-296583215-10.0.0.6-1542473394293:blk_1073741833_1009
>   file=/20170930.csv

I know this is not about missing block but more likely something else. But I can not figure out why. The code python code from the workbook using python2 kernel is:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('hello').setMaster('spark://spark-master:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# Read from HDFS
sparkSession = SparkSession(sc)
df_load = sparkSession.read.csv('hdfs://namenode:9000/20170930.csv')
df_load.show()
```

The problem comes at:

```
df_load = sparkSession.read.csv('hdfs://namenode:9000/20170930.csv')
```

I can't see anything in the different logs that gives me a clue. There are only INFO lines

Anybody who can give be a clue what to look for?

Comment: It must be something with the network, because if create containers (docker-compose up) instead of deploying (docker stack deploy) then everything works fine. But then I can not easily add new nodes for workers :(
Anybody got bde2020/hadoop and spark to work together with jupyter in swarm mode?

Comment: Did you ever get this question answered Jens? I have the same problem and am curious if you found a solution.

Comment: Sorry Chris no I did not. And I stil need to. But when I get it, I'll be sure to post it

Comment: the trick is to use dnsrr as the endpoint mode of your services. this resolved the issue for me. note that you can't mount ports to the host using dnsrr mode, though, which can be kinda tricky to work around. i can't post my full solution here b/c i developed it at work, but you can follow this tutorial to see the basics of what i'm talking about: https://blog.newnius.com/how-to-quickly-setup-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker.html

Comment: Do I need to use "endpoint_mode: dnsrr" for all my services (Hadoop, Spark, Jupyter and Hue) or just Hadoop?
And I notice that you create each slave services and by that not really using the full power of swarm as understand it. Is there a reason that they are not created as global?

Comment: BTW: I tried to add "endpoint_mode: dnsrr" to my composer file but get:  port published with ingress mode can't be used with dnsrr mode

Comment: i would use dnsrr just for hadoop and spark services. i didn't want to put the same set of services on every host in the swarm, hence not using the global mode. as for the problem re: port publishing, you can't publish a port to host when using dnsrr mode - just don't use dnsrr mode for the service that's running jupyter so that you can still map the port to host on that service and access jupyter on that port.

Comment: I would love to see a blog post where someone set up hadoop in docker swarm on eg. 3 docker-machines (I use HyperV) and den access hadoop from a machine outside the cluser. That is what I'm trying to do, but with no luck
I always get stuck on some communication problem internally with the network and hadoop
https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench was supposed to do that - but I can't get it to work

Comment: did you check out the blog post I linked to? I was able to use that to use swarm to do pretty much exactly what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that we cannot publish the ports if we use endpoint-mode=dnsrr (and we have to use dnsrr or there will be some problems for Hadoop).

So to expose the ports, we can start another container to publishes ports and routes the traffic to HDFS nodes. One available tool is socat.

Of course, you still have to set the hosts on that node.

see https://blog.newnius.com/setup-distributed-hadoop-cluster-with-docker-step-by-step.html

Comment: After testing this and mailing with Newnius I finally found out the problem was that I need to apply dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname = true on my client outside the swarm - then everything work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since Docker containers are ephemeral, it's possible the datanode container died, and therefore the data within, but the namenode still knows that the file used to exist.

I don't know about node-affinity rules in Swarm, but you should try to add volume mounts to the namenode and datanode containers, plus make sure they can only be scheduled on single machines (assuming you have more than one, since you are using Swarm rather than just Compose)

Probably the same, but I have made my own [Docker Compose](https://github.com/cricket007/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop/docker-compose.yml) with Hue, Juptyer, NameNode, and Datanode, and I did test it with PySpark

Comment: Thanks, but as I say I can read the file just fine from hue so its not at datanode not existing problem. In the namenode interface it shows that there is a datanode and that there is no problems
And there is a volume mount as seen in the composer file.
I'm only running on one machine to troubleshoot, but ja its mean to run on several machines as soon as I get it working.

Comment: It might be a Spark problem, or it could be a network problem, but I would suggest getting into a terminal of one of the containers and trying to run `hadoop fs -cat hdfs://namenode:9000/20170930.csv` (don't trust UI's)

Comment: Did that from the namenode and it lists the hole file just fine. So it's probably between spark and hadoop. But I have no clue how to figure it out

Comment: Are you able to make the hadoop containers and Spark containers share the same `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` for the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and `$HADOOP_HOME_CONF` paths?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm way over my head :) But I need this for a data analyse for my master project so...

As far as I can tell they do have same environment using https://github.com/gotthardsen/docker-hadoop-spark-workbench/blob/master/swarm/hadoop.env in the compose file for both spark and hadoop.